# ValueError while connecting to MongoDB cluster using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect to my MogoDB cluster at Atlas using Pymongo. But it's giving this error which I can't relate.

(Note: <mypasswordhere> is just for privacy purposes. I used the correct password there.)

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient

>>> CONNECTION_STRING = 'mongodb+srv://edusanketdk:<mypasswordhere>@cluster0.drpzp.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

>>> client = MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 718, in __init__
    self.__options = options = ClientOptions(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\client_options.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.__pool_options = _parse_pool_options(options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\client_options.py", line 132, in _parse_pool_options
    ssl_context, ssl_match_hostname = _parse_ssl_options(options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\client_options.py", line 98, in _parse_ssl_options
    ctx = get_ssl_context(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\ssl_support.py", line 159, in get_ssl_context
    ctx.load_verify_locations(certifi.where())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pyopenssl_context.py", line 276, in load_verify_locations
    self._callback_data.trusted_ca_certs = _load_trusted_ca_certs(cafile)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\ocsp_support.py", line 79, in _load_trusted_ca_certs
    _load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_data, backend))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 436, in load_pem_x509_certificate
    return rust_x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(data)
ValueError: error parsing asn1 value: ParseError { kind: InvalidValue, location: ["RawCertificate::tbs_cert", "TbsCertificate::serial"] }
```

Versions:

- python: 3.8.5
- pymongo: 3.12.1
- mongodb: 5.0

I have obtained the connection string using the specifications: python driver: 3.6+.

Comment: I'd say you're behind some firewall/router that blocks some certificate sources (has less CAs set as trusted than normally)? Are you in office or school network?

Comment: @h4z3 do you have a workaround for that? coz I just tried that on Kaggle, and it works just fine. So it's very obvious that it's my PC specific only.

Comment: Can you run the script in a new virtual environment ?